# "Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible" Laravel app on OVH

Tags: php, laravel, storage, ovh

I deployed my **Laravel** App on **OVH** server, It works nice, just avatars can't be loaded , it shows `403 error` 
I open logs and I find this error :

> Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /homez.1714/hdapocb/www/depot_documents/public/storage, referer: https://my_domain/admin/settings/user-profile

I've already run `php artisan storage:link` on server and I have permissions to access to storage folder.

**Permissions are like this :**

root folder : www/depot_documents `rwxrwxr-x` 
www/depot_documents/public : `rwxrwxr-x` 
symbolic link : www/depot_documents/public/storage :`rwxrwxrwx` 
www/depot_documents/storage : `rwxrwxr-x` 
www/depot_documents/storage/app : `rwxrwxr-x` 
www/depot_documents/storage/app/public : `rwxrwxr-x`

I don't know where's the mistake.

**Edit**

.htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        Options +FollowSymlinks
    </IfModule>
 
    RewriteEngine On
 
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
 
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
 
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please share more details. Is this an error thrown by PHP, or by Apache?

Comment: @NicoHaase no it's by OVH, because it works on localhost

Answer (score 1):

This error is related to PHP configuration settings, where the `open_basedir` is set to a strict value and restricts access to symbolic linking.

You can try and fix it by modifying the `open_basedir` in the `php.ini` file or just adding a `.htacces file in your Laravel app root directory.

Your .htacces file should contain this rule:

```php
php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

The rule above will disable the Laravel app settings for `open_basedir` giving access to symbolic linking.

I would suggest you read more about [Laravel File System Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#configuration) and [php.ini rules](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

Comment: Where I can found the `php.ini ` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a 403 because the link I used had an absolute path, starting with /home. Changing the link to a relative path, starting with ../ solved the issue.

The link was created by laravel's `php artisan storage:link`